# How to handle textbox popup in Excel?

Tags: python, excel, automation

I am trying to automate an excel with vba macros in it, one of those macros causes excel to display a popup textbox where user have to enter some test (optional can be left empty as well) and click on OK.
So far i have tried the code i found here which worked for normal popup boxes with only "OK" button but same is not working in this situation.

[image: Popup box]

Edit: As this needs to work without assuming that excel will always be in the foreground I can not use keyboard or mouse input libraries.

Here is the code i tried till now

```
class ButtonClicker(Thread):

    def __init__(self, title:str, interval:int):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self._title = title 
        self._interval = interval 
        self._stop_event = Event()   

    def stop(self):
        '''Stop thread.'''
        self._stop_event.set()

    @property
    def stopped(self):
        return self._stop_event.is_set()

    def run(self):
        while not self.stopped:
            try:
                time.sleep(self._interval)
                self._close_msgbox()
            except Exception as e:
                print(e, flush=True)

    def _close_msgbox(self):
        # find the top window by title
        hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, self._title)
        if not hwnd: return
        # find child button
        h_btn = win32gui.FindWindowEx(hwnd, None,'Button', None)
        if not h_btn: return

        # show text
        text = win32gui.GetWindowText(h_btn)
        print(text)

        # click button        
        win32gui.PostMessage(h_btn, win32con.WM_LBUTTONDOWN, None, None)
        time.sleep(0.2)
        win32gui.PostMessage(h_btn, win32con.WM_LBUTTONUP, None, None)
        time.sleep(0.2)
```

main python file:

```
from ButtonClicker import ButtonClicker
import win32
import xlwings as xw
import time

listener1 = ButtonClicker("test", 3)
listener1.start()
wb = xw.Book(r'test.xlsm')
for i in range(5):
    time.sleep(5)
# Run the VBA macro named 'MacroName'
    wb.macro('Rectangle2_Click')()
     
# close the child thread finally
listener1.stop()
```